# Project properties lost on external checkout

Tags: c++, eclipse, svn, svn-externals

Our company might be moving from CVS to Subversion soon. This has brought about an issue for us, which I am trying to solve.

For CVS and Eclipse, we were able to use team project set files to gather various modules and check them out together (http://vpms.de.csc.com/projectset/). This made it very easy to manage projects, since there was no need to remember each module in the project.

However, project sets do not support SVN. I know there is an 'externals' property for SVN that does approximately (or possible exactly) the same thing. I tried this. Now, for the problem:

When I use the externals property and checkout 2 modules in eclipse, their C/C++ project properties are lost, and so I cannot right click on them to say "build project" or "clean project". They appear to Eclipse to be folders with files in them.

Is there something I am missing here?

**EDIT**
When I check out each module separately, they check out as projects, so they do have the individual .project/.cproject/settings stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone needs this, here's what I found:

http://vpms.de.csc.com/projectset/

&

http://www.polarion.org/index.php?page=download&project=subversive

OR

http://www.giniality.com/old/update/projectset/

for Subversion + Project Set integration.

There is no need to break your project set. Once you have the integration plugins installed in Eclipse, all you need to do is change the source from the CVS server to SVN.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to place Eclipse project metadata into your source control system. Make sure all files starting with '.' in project root make it in along with the entire contents of the .settings directory.

Comment: I did not not check them in. I checked in the entire project. I did not ignore them, or delete them before checking them in. When I check out the modules separately, they check out as projects, which tells me the .project/.cproject files are in there.

Answer (score 1):

Subversion externals simply allows you to take files from one part of the repository and bring them in under a folder in your local checkout.  At my last company, we had a java source directory that called "commonSrc" that was an SVN External for another project's main "src" directory, but in the project it was brought into, it simply acted as another folder (as you are experiencing).

I never really liked that method and wouldn't recommend it unless you have only one/two modules.

In order to do what you are trying to do with SVN, you might have to checkout each project separately, and use "Module Dependencies" in the project's properties to create the proper dependencies in Eclipse.  You might be able to commit these project files so that the next person doesn't have to re-link them.

Comment: Unfortunately, the number is more like 15-20, which makes checking out each individual module inconvenient, inefficient and mostly a pain :\

Comment: What if you used externals to check out a single folder that contains the externalized 15-20 projects, but outside Eclipse?  Then you could do an Eclipse "Import Existing Projects", and search the checked out directory and find all the projects (assuming they are checked out with their .project files)